# How to know if a website is a single page application?

Tags: single-page-application

I have extremely little experience with web tech, only know basic HTML and CSS. I have an assignment where I'm supposed to evaluate a website and identify web techs that can help improve the site. One of the first things I want to figure out is whether the one I've chosen is a multi or single page application. I've been googling for hours for code that's 'typical' for SPA, but haven't found anything other than this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>Single Page Sliding Layout - Design Shack Demo</title>
<meta name="author" content="Jake Rocheleau">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://designshack.net/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" href="https://designshack.net/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
```

Does this indicate that it's a SPA? Or am I completely off track?
This is the website if that helps:
http://www.mrbottles.com/

Comment: looking at script tags is not going to tell you if it is a single page app.

Comment: In general, it's an SPA if navigating around in it doesn't lead to a full page load.
You can get a better understanding of the inner workings by using the browser's development tools and observe the network traffic

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, as mentioned, I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: The page you posted is no SPA. Basically if the frontend handles routing on its own without redirecting, its a SPA.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer is correct there isn't any flag to indicate if a web app is an SPA, also sometimes SPA can wrap regular web pages depending on the client. Recently Netflix moved their login page I believe into a regular html page and stripped out React SPA to only trigger once logged in or using certain features so like sign up / login / about are all regular pages. This helped increase page load times and less footprint on servers. Sometimes there can be custom javascript libs to create SPA other times it's easy to look for framework scrips like (angular, vue, react, knockout)

Comment: yes, it is an SPA because is stated on the title :)) maybe the assignment is less smart than you think. Joking. Watching at your html there is no way to detect if a routing is handled, at least from that header. you miss the body, maybe it gave us more clues

Comment: @lexith Thank you very much! I was so focused on that the URL changes on SPAs as well, but just looking at it now while clicking around it becomes obvious that it does redirect.

Comment: Look into yslow

Comment: a SPA will also change the url to make native browser history possible. Examples for SPA frameworks are angular, react, vue and such. basically all frontend frameworks nowadays

Comment: @FabioGuerrazzi The code is taken from a different site, that is an SPA indeed, but as dicussed I've now realised the www.mrbottles.com is not an SPA. But thank you for your help :)

Comment: ANd SPA is not always an improvement ;)

Comment: @epascarello haha yeah i realise it's a highly discussed subject, but we're supposed to follow trends as well, and I'd say SPA is a trend. Also, after writing a group report by myself I'm just looking for the easiest things, which at the moment is suggesting Angular

Comment: @lexith And you think this website could profit from Angular? That's what I'm thinking of proposing in the report.

Answer (score 26):

## SPAs - Single Page Applications

**Precursor**

One thing to get out of the way: there are *Single Page Applications* and *Single Page Websites*. There is a difference, although they both can have similarities.

A **Single Page Website** is a website that tries to put all the content on one page, you normally scroll through the page to get to the other sections and often there is a sticky navigation that follows you and tells you which section you're on. Also clicking on navigation is often an anchor link that will keep you on the page and jump you to the section without reloading (this can be done without javascript).

A **Single Page Application** is often seen in two flavors when page interaction or navigation occurs. One flavor is that the URL will have a `#` in it which the contents behind the `#` character change upon interactions. This is similar to the Single Page Website when clicking an anchor, except content is normally dynamically loaded in rather than the page scrolling to a section of the page. The other utilizes something called the browser history state. The javascript is able to change the page's path without reloading the window.

***Why do you care***? What is your mission, what are you trying to accomplish? Most people care about knowing if a page is an SPA because they're scoping the viability of whether or not their product offering will work with a client's website. Ultimately you want to know if content is dynamically loading in. If your offering modifies content on the page but content is changing there's no real great ways to fire your code off again upon SPA navigation/content change. Without knowing the reason, it makes it difficult to answer this question, but I will try to cover a wide scope.

### How do I detect an SPA?

It wasn't really stated whether you're trying to manually detect or programmatically detect an SPA. Unfortunately there are no flags that would be set and just because you find a framework doesn't mean that it is being utilized to make the page an SPA.

#### Manually Detecting an SPA

The most straightforward method to detect an SPA is to manually check it.

**Steps to Manually Detect SPA**

1. Open developer tools / inspector
2. Reload the page or navigate to it
3. Notice the timeline/waterfall of the requests
4. Click on a link or other interaction you have in concern

   - If the timeline refreshes and causes a page reload then it's not an SPA
   - If the timeline shows the first hits and additional hits after your interaction then you have an SPA.

**Programmatically Detect an SPA**

This can be complicated because SPAs can hook events and even prevent them from bubbling up or propagating if you're trying to listen to determine if the page is an SPA.

Here are a few ideas I came up with to detect SPAs.

---

When the window navigates away you can determine that a reload is about to take place. At this point you can say that the page is not an SPA. If you interacted and expected the reload to take place but did not then you have an SPA.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  var text = 'Not an SPA!';
  event.returnValue = text; 
  return text;
};
```

---

- You could hook/proxy the history state APIs to know if they were called.
- You could watch the history state. If a change occurs then you have an SPA
- You could come up with some crazy link/element click event watcher that delays for some arbitrary time and if the time passes and the timed event fires then it's probably an SPA otherwise the page navigated away and the event never finishes firing. This isn't great because you have to wait some arbitrary amount of time; what if you didn't want long enough and the page was being slow and still navigates away?

Answer (score -1):

If the history changes and the page is not reloaded then it is a SPA. Start with a red square in the bottom right. On history change update the color to green.

You need to look for stuff that uses window.history.

```js
const detectSPA = () => {
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  container.style.position = "fixed";
  container.style.bottom = "0";
  container.style.height = "1em";
  container.style.width = "1em";
  container.style.right = "0";
  container.style.zIndex = '1000';
  container.style.background = 'red';
  document.body.prepend(container);

  window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
    container.style.background = 'green';
  });
};
```